# How can enable pdo_mysql in php 7.1?

Tags: php

In `php.ini` , i had add `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`
But my connect still occur error:

> PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php(41): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123456')

and i search in `phpinfo`, it not exist.

i using apache 2.4 and php 7.1.

How can enable pdo_mysql in php 7.1?

Comment: Have you tried running php.exe app from your php folder ? It will show you an error if it unable to find a dll and you can check it the .dll exists in your php/ext folder

Comment: Did you restart the web server after enabling the extension?

Comment: C:\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll is exist

Comment: i download ver 7.1  VC14 x64 Thread Safe (2018-Jul-19 11:54:52) at https://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: yes i had restart

Comment: in phpinfo display: PDO drivers no value

Comment: Check the `extension_dir = "c:/php/ext/`  parameter in `php.ini` is pointing to the correct folder

Comment: thank you, it is ok

Comment: Do you have more than one PHP-version on your computer? Are you changing the correct `php.ini`-file?